# CakePHP 2: Redirect Loop with Auth

Tags: cakephp, authentication, redirect, acl

I am getting a redirect loop error and for the life of me I can't figure out how or why. Here are my settings:

**Router**

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')),
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home')
        ),
        'Session'
    );
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

    public function isAuthorized($user){
        return true;
    }

    function beforeFilter() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Super old question, I know, but this is what fixed my problem: `parent::beforeFilter();`.

Answer (score 2):

This may be of because you did not set the display() method as public. That's why it may redirecting to the same page and that webpage is not authenticated.

So you can put you "display() method" in your pages controller a public accessible using the following code:

```
 //Define following method in your controller PagesController.php
 function beforeFilter()
 {
      $this->Auth->allow('display');
 }
```

Hope it will work for you. Please ask if not worked for you.

Comment: What I think, There is no need to specify IsAuthroized() method in your AppController for the Auth Component initial setup. You may try it to use later.

Comment: Use $this->Auth->allow() to specify which actions ANYONE can view.

Use isAuthorized() to decide if a particular user can access an action.

If Auth->allow() is set to allow access to 'display', isAuthorized() won't be called for the display action - Auth->allow() overrides isAuthorized()

Comment: using $this->requestAction() in the view might include other controllers in the proccess. make sure they have the right permissions.